# Getting files and downloading them to a different directory

Tags: psftp

I can running a batch file with the following commands.  I am new to PSFTP

I want to download files from a remote server:
get /"test City School District.zip" =>lcd f:\Imports\RenLearn\"Test City School District.zip"

I am getting am error saying it is unable to open =>Lcd   Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, `lcd` means "local change directory". You are giving `lcd` a filename not a directory name.

Second, you need to change directory before you `get` the file.

Your session should look something like:

```
open <name of remote server>

...

lcd f:\Imports\RenLearn
cd /
get "test City School District.zip"

...
```

See [Transferring Files with PSFTP](http://www.msci.memphis.edu/~simmonsj/c4262/notes/psftp.html) for more information.